How to get detailed Windows OS namestring, version and kernel-version via win32 API?
I am aware of versionifo and versinfoex structures, %OS% environment variable, and some other API calls via win32, for example these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/system-information-functions.
However, I don't seem to be able to find "pretty-printed" version of the OS name, as they print it out in their "about" dialog themselves. Under "Windows specifications" tab in the "about" dialog, they say this:
Utgåva          Windows 11 Pro
Version         23H2
Installerad ‎2024-‎01-‎24
OS-version  22631.3593
Gränssnitt  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1003.0

(Sorry for the Swedish).
I am particularly interested to programmatically obtain the first, second and third fields, hopefully as a C calls (calling it from a Lisp via FFI), but any language will do.
To note, there is a command-line program, "systeminfo" which prints lots of hardware, and some OS info. That command also output as "OS Name" the above first field, and as "OS version" the third field above, but omits the second field. The other command-line program, "ver", prints the following:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3593]

Can anybody point me to the respective Win32 functions and corresponding structures to get this information as printed above? The "usual" GetVersionInfoEx() & co do not seem to produce this information.
Edit: The answer provided by IInspectable seems to be what I wanted. Mentioned in the comments below.
Thank you for all the answers and the patience.

look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

I see. Thank you very much for the very fast answer. There are though some discrepancies there: for example "ProductName" says "Windows 10 Pro", not "Windows 11 Pro", but I see that the other stuff is obtainable through various keys there.

internal version of win 11 is still 10. so really 11 not exist in some sense

Yes, I understand that RbMm, but wondered where they print their info from for the "about" screen. Perhaps, they have hardcoded it somewhere, IDK really, but I guess they have it available in some string or structure internally, and are able to pull it out programmatically when they need it, since at least two different applications are showing the same string. Also, I don't understand why people are down voting the question. It is an honest question.

This has just never made much sense. Remember when Windows 8.1 had version number 6.3?  :-)

I remember when they upgraded from NT 4.0 to NT 5.0, and the year 2000, made it before their engineers managed to get the OS finished :). We got NT 5.0 (W2K Pro) and NT 5.1 (Win XP). I guess Win XP was what NT 5.0 was supposed to be, but the marketing department couldn't miss the year 2K hallmark.
I have no problem with them keeping different "major" versions of the kernel and the OS, just they keep the things documented. Recently I worked with the console API, and had to switch to "raw" mode. The MSDN docs were OK, but slightly imprecise and two flags are undocumented.

That's an incorrect rendition of events. XP was NT 6.0, until (in-house) testing revealed that shitty software out there compared to the major version "5" for equality. Don't blame Microsoft for not breaking third-party software when a client chose to upgrade from Windows 2000 to Windows XP. Marketing has no say in internal versioning, whatsoever. How do folks come up with conspiracy theories like that?

And so they didn't as you say: internal versioning was 5.0 and 5.1; external W2K and XP, no? If you asked marketing internal version would surely be 6.0 :-).
It is not a conspiracy, it is a half-joke, half-true. I don't know how old you are, but I am old enough to remember the wait and the delays of NT5.0. It should have come out in about 98, but it didn't. They had a lot of problems to push out NT5.0. I have read both The New Old Thing and have been following the blog for years, so I know how much they care about backward compatibility and not breaking 3rd party apps.

However, I have never heard that they changed the internal version of Windows XP because some "shitty software" did the wrong comparison. Perhaps you can share the story with us if you have a link? It would be an interesting read and a detail of history I didn't know about.
When it comes to riding on the hype of the year 2000, it was ginormous. In all parts of IT and society. They didn't mean to release more Windows 9x after the 98SE, yet they did Windows ME. Back at the time, it was clear MS would not miss the Y2K hype to release a new OS, but I think they surprised everyone with ME.

The Old New Thing I meant :-)

You can get all the information you need to construct the "pretty printed" string yourself. So what's the problem? There doesn't need to be a OS API that produces the exact string you want in order for you to be able to produce that string - it just takes a little work on your part after parsing the data you get from the OS.

@JesperJuhl "You can get all the information you need to construct the "pretty printed" string yourself." - You do not. There is no official document that exhaustively lists all shipped product names. And even if such a list existed, it would be missing future releases (for reasons obvious to some of us).

Thanks @IInspectable. I just came in to write the same. To note also I asked about the "build number" (232H in the example above) and revision numbers too, not just the name.

Microsoft in their great wisdom decided that providing a simple version number for their OS was not what developers wanted. So instead they have provided this set of Version Helper functions. You can still use the GetVersionEx function, but it may disappear at some point in the future. I have not found a definitive sample that reliably provides the standard version value, even though it exists in the registry. But, also be aware that Microsoft advise against relying on the registry so that also may chgange without notice.

Thank you for the answer. These are indeed useful if we need to ensure a minimal version of Windows is available, however, not so if we want to print the system info. Think posix "uname" function and utsname struct.
If we can't rely on registry, and they don't provide this info via some API, what are we supposed to use?

@myname You are supposed to put up with what Microsoft offer, I am afraid. But you are not alone, lots of people find this somewhat unhelpful.

This does nothing to answer the question. It is distinctly about turning the version information (which is sufficiently exposed by the various API calls) into a human-readable text string. The latter is what this question is asking for. Rambling about Microsoft being (allegedly) incapable of providing read-to-use system information doesn't help.

Happy, and happy, it is a definition question. I am just trying to be polite and positive :). I did hint that the info is not relevant; the helper functions are useful in the other context, than what I need them for.
To answer your other comment: yes I understand I have to put with what MS provides. I am OK with that, but I am asking if they provide something I am not aware of and have missed somehow because I don't seem to be able to find those version strings I see in the "about" box. I refuse to believe they are stitching strings together in some dialog label based on a number :).

@myname New contributor remember to accept the answer you want.

Unfortunately, I don't think this is the answer on the question, but I don't like to down vote people who are trying to be helpful.  The comment by RbMm about the registry lookup seem to be the closest to what I seek thus far. I don't know if that is the answer just yet.

But that is rather the point I was trying to make. Since Microsoft adopted this new scheme, there does not appear to be a simple and definitive answer.

Yes, I understand, but there has to be some way? They are doing it themselves. I can't imagine any reason why they wouldn't expose such a simple functionality to application programmers. Hopefully we don't have to go through some CIM interface and XML parsing just to get the pretty-printed OS name as they use it.
Can you develop more why they discourage the use of registry? Do you have some link to msdn article or something? Forgive me for being a PITA, I am just trying to get a bit more informed.

Take a look at this answer by @IInspectable. Something I also need to try.

@myname The system doesn't expose a function for this because it is of limited utility. The system does provide an interface to gather version information as structured data. But even that is rarely useful outside of reporting diagnostics. You certainly don't want to use this data for run-time decisions.

Thank you; now that is useful. No, I don't need this to do runtime decisions based on minor versions of Windows, I leave that to win32 implementers at Microsoft. I prefer to use their public API for the stuff I need to do. But I do need (rather to say want), to print some details, and didn't see a way to print out if I am on Windows 10 or 11. I also got intrigued by looking at about box, so wanted to learn which API they use. I understand now and will look more at DDK functions. Thank you.
